# stateful and stateless methods of stream

Tags: java, java-stream, stateless, side-effects, stateful

In the interface Stream :

The intermediate operations are classifiable in stateful and stateless. They impact the result of a parallel Stream.

Only two terminal operations are nondeterministic methods: findAny() and forEach(Consumer). They impact the result of a parallel Stream.

The intermediate stateless operations could have a side-effect if they execute a lazy operation. This impact the result of a parallel Stream.

The intermediate operations are classifiable in:

**Stateful**

- distinct()
- sorted()
- limit (long l)
- skip (long l)

**Stateless**

- map (Function f)
- flatMap (Function f)
- filter (Predicate p)
- peek (Consumer c)

These are my two question:

1. Stateless intermediate methods

   - If I call stateless intermediate methods on parallel stream + nondeterministic forEach(), I will obtain the same result of sequential stream, but with different order.
   - If I call stateless intermediate methods on parallel stream + nondeterministic findAny(), I will obtain an unpredictable result.
   - If I call stateless intermediate methods on parallel stream + normal terminal operation, I will obtain the same result of sequential stream.
   - If I call stateless intermediate methods on parallel stream + normal terminal operation with side-effect, I will obtain an unpredictable result.
2. Stateful intermediate methods

   - If I call stateful intermediate methods + nondeterministic forEach(), I will obtain the same result of a sequential stream, but with different order.
   - If I call stateful intermediate methods + nondeterministic findAny(), I will obtain an unpredictable result.
   - If I call stateful intermediate methods + normal terminal operation, I will obtain the same result of a sequential stream.

Are these rules correct?

2. The order of a Stream elements is "encounter order", except if I call the BaseStream method: unordered(). Does the order of the elements impact the results of a stream (in the presence of stateful or stateless methods)? If yes, how?

Thanks a lot!

A.

Comment: There is a good documentation to assert those rules - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: Can you *not* ask multiple questions?  That would make the responses to your question *quite* broad and difficult to actually follow, and make it harder for others in the future to actually look for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess both conditions 1 and 2 are true. I want to add some operations.

`reduce` also is part of the stateful operation.

`forEach` is part of the stateless operations.

Please note that stateless operations can become stateful if they create side effects.

The third statement is not totally correct. If a stream is ordered and we process it in parallel, the stream will remain ordered when used with the stateless operations. That's why we need to call the method `unordered()` on the stream to make it unordered and improve the efficiency.